# Using fetch data to post to API

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch

I have fetch data I am trying to re-use this data to push to a DB that then triggers a stored procedure

I have tried reusing the variable on a new function and get undefined, I don't even know where to start if using the existing axios get.

```
    getEFID = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const EFID = e.target.elements.EFID.value;
        console.log(EFID);
        axios.get(`/api/vWEFID/${EFID}`)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                const DAEFForm = res.data;
                this.setState({
                    DAEFForm: res.data
                })
                console.log("Getting transport Information...", DAEFForm)
            });
    }

    TransportEF = (e) => {
        //const tEF = 
        this.setState({ show: false });
        e.preventDefault();
        const TransportEF = e.target.elements.getEFID.DAEFForm.data;
        /*axios.get(`/api/tEFID/`)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                const TransportEF = res.data;
                this.setState({
                    TransportEF: res.data
                })*/
        alert('Transporting EF!')
        console.log(TransportEF);
           // })
    }
```

If I can get the data out of the getEFID to TransportEF or somehow use the existing getEFID to console log the data then I can uncomment the API thats already set to post the data to the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue correctly, you want to use response data from the API call in `getEFID` function as a payload within the API call inside the `TransportEF` function.

Since you tagged React and I can see `setState` being called, and assuming `this` is properly bound in both cases, all you really need to reference that data within `TransportEF` is `this.state.DAEFForm`.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: thanks @krukid, I have set the state like this but not bound the setState

```
state = {
        DAEFForm: []
    }
```
When I bind this using this.DAEFForm = this.DAEFForm.bind(this);

it throws an error Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined, so trying to work around that.

Comment: I added this.state.DAEFForm; instead of the e.target.elements.getEFID.DAEFForm.data; and it looks like it is working now, thanks for your help.